# Directory traversal security issue

Tags: java, security

I have a Java webapp which is vulnerable to the directory transversal (aka path transversal) attack via URL encoding. After being authenticated:

- if I hit http://localhost:8080/Web/WEB-INF/web.xml, I get a 404 (which is fine)
- if I hit http://localhost:8080/Web/%c0%ae/WEB-INF/web.xml, I can read the file (which is obviously not fine)

As per the Servlet spec., the WEB-INF folder is not supposed to be accessible publicly, but somehow it works in this case.
I'm using Websphere 5.1 with Java 1.4, Spring Security 2.0.5 and Struts 1.3.
From what I read, it seems to be related to the encoding, %c0%ae being '.' (dot) in UTF-8.

I tried the same thing on a different webapp which runs in a different environment (Tomcat 6 with Java 7, Spring Security 3 and Spring MVC) and I wasn't able to reproduce the problem. This second webapp has a filter to force encode the pages in UTF-8 (`org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter`), so I tried the same configuration on the first webapp, but it didn't do the trick.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way you can update your Spring and/or Java versions on the system this will be deployed on? Sounds like CVE-2010-3700

Comment: Unfortunately not, this is not under my control.

Comment: Then I suggest a limited release. This is a known problem with this version and if the customer wont upgrade to a new version he will have to live with the trouble it gives him. Not very useful I know. Sorry maybe someone else will come up with something.

Comment: I can see that indeed it is a known issue. Thanks, Eduard.

Comment: Running old versions of software with many published vulnerabilities probably isn't the greatest idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question.
So with the limited options I had, what I ended up doing is add in the Spring Security configuration file a security rule such as

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/**/WEB-INF/**" access="no-access"/>
```

It restricts access to WEB-INF to the 'no-access' role which is in fact not a role. That prevents access to all users. It is not ideal but will do the trick until there is an upgrade.

Comment: You should probably add a rule for META-INF as well.

Comment: You can define security rules in META-INF? How does this work?

Comment: No, I meant you should use the same type of rule to block access to META-INF, not just WEB-INF.

Answer (score 1):

You could fix or deny these requests before they hit Websphere by proxying them through another webserver/appserver or [Web application firewalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_firewall#Web_application_firewalls). Either another Java app server or possibly something like [Nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/nginx) or [Varnish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish_%28software%29) could do the trick.

Of course, the *real* solution is to upgrade. This is just a band-aid, that could be subverted. It's really the wrong way to "fix" security problems.

Comment: I don't have the option to add this kind of component unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The filter changes the character encoding for the body of the request, not the URL.

To set the URL encoding in tomcat, you need to add an attribute in the <Connector> element of server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: Thanks Maurice, but is there an equivalent in Websphere?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't upgrade (ancient WebSphere + Java 1.4, ouch!), one possible workaround (more of a hackaround, really) is to write a simple filter, mapped to every request, that does the proper charset conversion and rejects invalid requests.

I'm sure with some digging you can find an implementation that checks for things you may not have thought of.

Of course that still leaves 8 years worth of other security (not to mention productivity) problems.

#### Oops

Didn't notice didn't notice how old the question is.

Comment: How do you determine a request is invalid though? Would you have to manually keep up-to-date a list of such requests?

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author davidandrade
 */
public class RestrictURL implements Filter {

    private FilterConfig fcgConfFiltr_t;

    private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger log = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(RestrictURL.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        fcgConfFiltr_t = filterConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        String strUrlPetici_t = req.getRequestURL().toString();
        String strUrlBase___t = strUrlPetici_t.substring(0, strUrlPetici_t.indexOf(fcgConfFiltr_t.getServletContext().getContextPath()) + fcgConfFiltr_t.getServletContext().getContextPath().length());

        try {

            res.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
            log.info("URL Req: " + strUrlPetici_t);

            if (strUrlPetici_t.toLowerCase().contains("%co") || strUrlPetici_t.toLowerCase().contains("%ae")) {
                sendErrorRedirect(req, res, "/404.jsf", new Exception("DirectoryTransversalRequired"));
            } else {
                try {
                    fcgConfFiltr_t.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(strUrlPetici_t).forward(request, response);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("", e);
            sendErrorRedirect(req, res, "/404.jsf", e);

        }
    }

    protected void sendErrorRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String errorPageURL, Throwable e) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute("exception", e);
        fcgConfFiltr_t.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(errorPageURL).forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        fcgConfFiltr_t = null;
    }

}
```

And add filter to my web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>DirectoryTransversalFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.sec.RestrictURL</filter-class> <!-- mandatory -->
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>DirectoryTransversalFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```